# how to place text e.g. with h4 tag next to icon?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently individualizing the Hugo theme https://github.com/themefisher/vex-hugo

A demo can be found here: https://themes.gohugo.io/theme/vex-hugo/

Under the features there are nice icons with some text. I want to place the headings next to the icons.

In the html code a loop is used to place the text - which is defined in a yml file for static site generator Hugo - like this for the left icons and text:

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ range .left_side }}
        <div class="mb-40 text-center text-md-left">
          <i class="d-inlin-block h2 mb-10 {{ .icon }}"></i>
          <h4 class="font-weight-bold mb-2">{{ .title | markdownify }}</h4>
          <p>{{ .content | markdownify }}</p>
        </div>
        {{ end }}
```

I've added style="display: inline;" to the h4-tag, which will place the icons beside the text

[image]

But, with severe side effect, i.e. the nice arrangement (is it center?) of the three icon-text elements in the container next to the image is destroyed. Thus, I have to find another way. In addition I want to add more space between icon and text.

Compare first (good) to lower (bad) image
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you always want the icon and heading text to be in a row format with icon on the left and header on the right?

Comment: yes. for all elements

Comment: Did you try using `display: flex` with `align-items: center`?

Comment: No. Where should I  place both elements?

Comment: Please include all relevant HTML and CSS necessary to reproduce the issue you are seeing.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Puuh. I'm not that experienced and the custom css file is huge. I will try to figure out what is really used and needed here. Most is standard bootstrap 4, I guess.

Comment: Why not move this `<i class="d-inlin-block h2 mb-10 {{ .icon }}"></i>` into the `h4` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the `h4` in CSS `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;`. Even when the icon is larger than the text it will be centered vertically.

Here's the code example:

```css
.bi {
  font-size: 50px; /* This is only added to show the centering */
}

#testOne {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#testTwo {
  font-size: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<h4 id="testOne">
  <i class="bi bi-alarm"></i>
  Test
</h4>

<h4 id="testTwo">
  <i class="bi bi-alarm"></i>
  Test
</h4>
```